# Kernel Panic El Capitan 10.11.2 4MEM/60

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, kernel-panic

The machine:
late 2011 15in MacBook Pro
i7 Sandybridge 2.2 GHz
8 GB/8 GB (1333MHz,DDR3) = 16 GB RAM
Intel HD graphics 3000 512MB

The background:
I have had this Mac for awhile now. I have dropped it twice now and both pretty hard times (dropped open). After this I started to notice kernel panics initially when I would open up a folder full of pictures. This continued and El Capitan was released so I figured I should just wipe it clean and start fresh, thinking the problem might be software related.

After initially just installing the new OS over the existing one(leaving all my previous data intact), I finally just decided to wipe it clean and do a fresh install. This was complete and I thought that I might have solved the issue.

I started to experience more and more frequent KPs yet still no predictable schedule to when they would occur(some a hour apart, some ten minutes). At this point I started to look into the hardware side. I ran AHT (both sticks of RAM) and I got a 4MEM/60/40000000 error = memory module.

Once the error pointed to my issue I then began to open up the MBPs' backplate and preceded to reseat the memory in hopes of a simple fix, which did not work. I then tested each stick separately and in each respective bank. The results were as follows:

```
bank/dimm01(lower)  
stick A = no error  
stick B = no error  
bank/dimm02(upper)  
stick A = 4MEM/60  
stick B = 4MEM/60
```

I figure at this point that the bank/dimm02(upper) slot is bad (probably damaged from a drop of something similar).

I take stick B seat it into bank/dimm01(lower) and boot it off one stick. 
Just to be extra sure I ran [rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/) too and it came back clean. Finally I thought the problem was 'resolved'.

24 later, on the single stick boot, guess what? another KP and not just one, a nice and lovely triple kick of repeated KP for my holiday splendor.

Does anyone have any insight? All info is appreciated.

Most recent kernel panic log:

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f837c350e): "AGC GPU REGISTER RESTORE FAILED : rdar://7254528, VendorID invalid"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.6/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/AGCPowerManagement.cpp:1158
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810b4abdb0 : 0xffffff8000cde792 
0xffffff810b4abe30 : 0xffffff7f837c350e 
0xffffff810b4abe70 : 0xffffff7f837c6324 
0xffffff810b4abea0 : 0xffffff80012bac13 
0xffffff810b4abf00 : 0xffffff8000d12afa 
0xffffff810b4abfb0 : 0xffffff8000dcbf77 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.12.6)[44D361A1-4938-3AA5-9F73-9C909B66214B]@0xffffff7f837b8000->0xffffff7f837cbfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.12.6)[1654475C-9A4B-386C-AFA8-0A530194A2F9]@0xffffff7f837a5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[CBAE26D8-0ACB-3C1F-8347-FDCA67EC40B3]@0xffffff7f817b3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[6ADFE830-2986-35D2-8C2F-6ABEDBC94F6A]@0xffffff7f8152c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[48AC8EA9-BD3C-3FDC-908D-09850215AA32]@0xffffff7f82049000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[EBCEDD19-7230-3FB6-94B7-075ABA534875]@0xffffff7f837b3000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15C50

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 17EA3101-D2E4-31BF-BDA9-931F51049F93
Kernel slide:     0x0000000000a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8000c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000b00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 130972371365
last loaded kext at 45090176242: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f82f65000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.21
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    203.14
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.4.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: Discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27630656#27630656

Comment: It's already been resolved, bmike helped me down the most efficient/practical path, and the machine is being repaired at apple currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Graphics crash from this…

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f837c350e): "AGC GPU REGISTER RESTORE FAILED : rdar://7254528, VendorID invalid"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.6/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/AGCPowerManagement.cpp:1158
```

I'd check with Apple whether you have one of the machines with a known problem -
[MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Comment: Even if this isn't a covered repair - flat rate $300 rework of all the parts that are bad isn't that costly when you consider trying to buy used logic board and swapping it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The machine was taken to Apple, and test were ran to see if it qualified for the repair extension program, it did not.

I've ran a few other sticks of RAM in the Dimms but to no avail, still random KPs. I'm supposing at this point that it is something with the logic board, memory controller... and at this time weighing my options accordingly.

UPDATE: The machine is being repaired at apple, new logic board.

Thanks for all your insight
cheers